# how to delete my skeptics account

Tags: discussion

How to delete my skeptics account ? Or remove a question which I asked, because later I regretted asking it ? I renamed my account as please delete me , but still the admin did not remove it ? I do not want to delete my entire stack exchange account. But the delete specific account is hidden somewhere , I could not find any options to delete.

Comment: Wow, your 1 question is not exactly the most offensive weve seen - not by a long way.

Answer (score 2):

We don't delete useful content, so if you have asked a question with upvoted answers you won't be able to remove it and moderators also won't delete it in most cases. If the question is downvoted, you can flag a mod to remove it, and we might delete it if we agree that the question doesn't provide any lasting value to the site.

If you just don't want to appear as the author of a question, flag the post and write that. This is not something we moderators can do, but some SE employees can disassociate the question from your account.

To get deleted, either use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page, or flag one of your own posts and request deletion. Putting "please delete me" in your profile is also very helpful to make your intent clear.